# Windows service fails to start in windows 2003 server

Tags: c#, windows-services

I've **installed my windows service** which worked fine in the local environment in a **windows 2003 server**. After installation when i tried to start the windows service it **fails by giving a pop up as follows**:

"Could not start windows service on local computer
Error 1053:Service could not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"

When i checked **the event log** it shows another error which says:

"**EventType clr20r3, P1 MyWindowsservice.exe, P2 1.0.0.0, P3 4cefad85, P4 mscorlib, P5 2.0.0.0, P6 471ebc5b, P7 e4, P8 10, P9 system.security.security, P10 NIL.**"

Any one please tell what is the problem and how to solve it...

Comment: Does your service depend on event sources existing in Event Log?  If so, you need to ensure that the sources are created prior to the service attempting to write to the Event Log.  It sounds odd, but I've seen similar errors when my event source did not exist on the deployment server.

Comment: Yes my service do create a custom event log. When i tried it in my local machine(windows 7) the log was created automatically. But when i tried to do the same in windows 2003 server i can't find the custom log in the event viewer.

Comment: was it working well without logging events? and did you configure for all user accounts?

Comment: The service was built to run as local service. When i changed the logon to local system it got started.

Comment: That answers your own questions. Local service account does not have enough permission to create the event logs. Local system has much more permission so using that account works.

Answer (score 1):

It was the **permission issue** for **creating custom event log**. At first i created the windows service setup to run as local service. I think the local service has limited permissions and when i changed the **log on account to local system account** it got started.